# Setting radio buttons with jQuery while auto-refreshing the page

Tags: jquery, radio-button

I have written the following jQuery for autorefreshing a page containing a poll (to keep updating the current winning option)

```
function update() {
  var vote_radio = $('input:radio[name=vote_radio]:checked').val();
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'index.php',
    data: 'refresh=true&maintain_radio='+ vote_radio,
    timeout: 2000,
    success: function(data) {
      $("#current_body").html(data);
      $("#notice_div").html(''); 
      $("[name=vote_radio]").filter("[value="+vote_radio+"]").attr("checked","checked");
      window.setTimeout(update, 2000);
    },
    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      $("#notice_div").html('Timeout contacting server..');
      window.setTimeout(update, 60000);
    }
});
};

$(document).ready(update);
```

There is a radiobutton poll on the page named "vote_radio", I also use the following code with that, to Ajax the answers to the server:

```
    $(function() {  
  $('.error').hide();
  $('.failure').hide();
  $('.success').hide();
  $(".vote_submit").click(function() {
        if (!$("input[@name='name']:checked").val()) {
            $('.error').show();
            return false;
        }
        var vote_radio = $('input:radio[name=vote_radio]:checked').val();;
        var dataString = 'vote_radio='+ vote_radio;
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "index.php",
          data: dataString,
          success: function() {
            $('.success').show();               
            $('.failure').hide();               
          },
          error: function() {
            $('.failure').show();               
            $('.success').hide();               
          }
        });
        return false;
  });
});
```

The problem I'm having with all this is that if a user selects their option WHILE the page is auto-refreshing it puts the selected radio option back to how it was WHEN the page started auto-refreshing, which is frustrating.

Also, if the .success class has been told to appear by the second script, when the first script autorefreshes the page it hides the success class again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you reverting the `vote_radio` element back to the value before initiating the AJAX call ?

Just read it right before overwriting it, so you keep the current value (*even if it changed without being submitted yet*)

so just change the success callback to

```
success: function(data) {
      var vote_radio = $('input:radio[name=vote_radio]:checked').val();
      $("#current_body").html(data);
      $("#notice_div").empty(); 
      $("[name=vote_radio]").filter("[value="+vote_radio+"]").attr("checked","checked");
      window.setTimeout(update, 2000);
    }
```

---

But, in general, the correct way would be to update only the parts of the page that need updating, and not the whole page.. that is the whole point of AJAX..

Comment: Thanks for answering. However, when I substitute in your callback function the whole function doesn't run.

What I really need to do is keep checking if the page needs updated, and if it does, then run the AJAX. The page content changes every 120 seconds, do you have an idea how I can somehow keep the time-checker running in the background, and let it call the refresh function when the time drops below zero?

Thanks again.